# Working for a manager who doesn't manage!

Tags: manager

### SITUATION:

I have been with the company I am with for over **15 years**.  Let me give some background information before I ask my question.

**First 5 years**

When I first started I reported to say *Manager 1*.  *Manager 1* was great... very knowledgeable and challenged me big time.  At the time I was a new programmer and loved my work as well as my professionalism.

**Next 5 years**

*Manager 1* retired earlier than he was due and I was then moved to another manager, *Manager 2*.
This manager was in charge of IT in general.  My first few months with this manager were odd.  He was nothing like *Manager 1*.  He never had meetings, he never had any direction.  Three other guys reported to this manager and a lot of them sat around all day watching YouTube videos or putting bandages on problems. 
*Manager 2* wanted things to stay the way they are.  He didn't like if I helped another department or created any additional applications.  My reviews with *Manager 2* were odd as well.  He said my emails or training seminars were too detailed.  That I sometimes worked "too hard".

**Years 11-13**

After 5 years I put some hints to the VP that I was really looking to be challenged. Within a couple of weeks I received an offer from the VP to become a supervisor and report directly to our company director. I learned a TON! *Manager 3* (the director) was just as good as *Manager 1*. They held status meetings, they innovated, and we got stuff DONE!

**Recent few years**

*Manager 3* was moving and decided now to leave the company. The CEO put me back on the team of *Manager 2*.  I could tell on *Manager 2's* face that he was not happy. I was able to take my subordinates, who reported directly to me, with me.  Now the *Manager 2* has put us in a different office where we cannot easily communicate with other IT members. He insisted this is simply to give us quiet time while we code.

- *Manager 2* has never stopped in to talk to anyone from our group.
- I've talked and sent emails to *Manager 2* expressing the importance of group activities such as lunches or team get-together. **No response**
- I've asked for training for myself and my group members. **No responses**
- He never shows up to any of the meetings I schedule.

### QUESTION:

I have a meeting with the VP next week about some other application we are working on and was wondering if it would be okay to bring this situation UP?

Comment: Hi Mike, and welcome to Workplace. This is a lot of text and you might benefit from [edit]ing it and making it a bit more concise, there's a lot of content here that seems more like a rant than a helpful addition or clarification.

Comment: Personally I think the post may be long because op wants to give you some history.  Joe your questions already answered in the last few sentences.  Good question.

Comment: I think the post yes has a lot of content but editing it out would lose history that op wants to provide.  Case in point op from experience appears to be hard working with seniority and has a manager that doesn't care and could also feel threatened by his knowledge.

Comment: I nearly missed the question in this and I'm not convinced it's actually a very useful one. Whether you can go over your manager's head to bring up his performance issues is very company-specific and culture-dependent and only the OP is well-placed to judge the pros and cons of doing so.

Comment: @liienthal I must not be reading this right.  Op mentioned he tried discussing this with his boss but is ignored.  So how exactly is he going over his managers head??

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @Lilienthal I would add that something like that has been asked and answered already: [How do I respectfully go above my manager?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/how-do-i-respectfully-go-above-my-manager)

Comment: @gnat Yes I assumed as much but didn't manage to find that question during a cursory search. This does seem to be a (particularly long-winded) duplicate.

Comment: You're not asking a real or worthwhile question, and the questions worth asking aren't even being discussed here: a) Why don't you try to get them to promote you? (or give you Mgr2's job? Ask them for direct feedback why they haven't promoted you) b) Why don't you quit and get a job at some place that values your technical experience? (like say where did Mgr3 go to?) Or at minimum c) Why don't you get your VP to scope out a way to get your job done with minimal/zero interaction with Mgr2? Most VPs won't have the time and energy to smooth your relationship with Mgr2. (Is VP trustworthy?)

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as there is a question it seems to be "My manager doesn't want to talk to me, I went up the hierarchy and got nowhere, now what?"

The first step is to work out what exactly *you* want to have happen. Make a list, cross out the thing that are implausible. If you want someone fired but can't imagine management doing so, don't mention it.

Once you know what you want, build a case for it. For each request, make a short explanation that covers: what the problem is, an example of it, your solution, and how your solution fixes the problem. That is what you should take to the VP next week.

Based on your post above, I suggest working hard to keep that list very short and very factual. Resist the temptation to throw in everything that's ever happened. Make sure everything you say points towards the outcome you want. Focus on a bullet point style list of "this is bad. Here is how I want you to help me fix it".

[How to get things done when your line manager does not manage?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52458/how-to-get-things-done-when-your-line-manager-does-not-manage) and [Managing Up: How do I “manage” a boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/managing-up-how-do-i-manage-a-boss-who-doesnt-know-how-to-set-expectation) contain somewhat relevant advice. There are better posts but my search skills have temporarily deserted me.

Comment: I never went up the hierarchy, that is my question...I am wondering if it is worth doing such a thing.  Why is it that laziness is accepted in the workplace?  I don't care if you are an employee or a manager why can't we just work..why is everything have to be so political?

Comment: People are political, that's just part of life. Workplace.SE is (mostly) about how to handle those politics and professional/social interactions